# как реализовать сортировку массива размером 10^7 используя только поразрядные операции?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Необходимо отсортировать массив семизначных чисел размером 10^7, используя только поразрядные операции. я разобрался с реализацией через bitset, но преподаватель такое решение принимать отказался. файлы так же запрещено использовать. только ввод с клавиатуры.

'''

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

const int arr_Size = 10000000;

void sort(int* arr, int n) {
    
    bitset<arr_Size - 1000000>* bitArr = new bitset <arr_Size - 1000000>;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bitArr->set(arr[i] - 1000000);
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_Size - 1000000; i++) {
        if (bitArr->test(i)) {
            arr[index] = i + 1000000;
            index++;
        }
    }
    delete bitArr;
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int size;
    int number;
    cout << "Введите количество чисел исходного массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    int* arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Введите число: ";
        cin >> number;
        arr[i] = number;
    }
    cout << "Отсортированный массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << "  ";
    cout << endl;
    delete arr;
}
```

'''

Comment: Ввод десяти миллионов чисел с клавиатуры? Однако... А по алгоритму - книга Седжвика "Алгоритмы на C++" поможет.

Comment: То есть операцию сравнения (<) использовать нельзя. Значит, быстрая сортировка и компаратор на поразрядных операциях., я правильно понял?

Comment: Ну если числа семизначные, то можно использовать сортировку подсчётом, а это разновидность поразрядной сортировки.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не соответствует заданию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировка сортировкой, а нужно сделать компаратор чисел на порязрядных операциях.

Начинаем с самого левого бита и идём вправо, пока у обоих чисел биты равны. Как только не равны, то там, где бит 0 - число меньше. Так, можно заксорить два числа и искать слева направо единицу в результате, а потом смотреть, у которого числа 0 в этой позиции.

Comment: Можно именно поразрядной сортировкой, а не обменной.

Comment: @Harry возможно, я неправильно понял задачу.

Answer (score 3):

Даже интересно стало... От вас не это хотят?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

template<unsigned_integral I>
void sort(I*a, size_t n)
{
    I*b = new I[n];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 8*sizeof(I); ++i)
    {
        size_t k = 0;
        I mask = 1 << i;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) if ((a[j]&mask) == 0) b[k++] = a[j];
        for(size_t j = 0; k < n; ++j) if ((a[j]&mask) != 0) b[k++] = a[j];
        I*t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
    delete[]b;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    constexpr size_t N = 10000000;
    unsigned int * a = new unsigned int[N];
    default_random_engine g(random_device{}());
    uniform_int_distribution d(0,1000000000);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) a[i] = d(g);

    sort(a,N);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) cout << a[i] << "\n";

}
```

Возиться с устойчивой сортировкой "на месте" не стал, просто выделил еще один массив в памяти...

Comment: Насколько я понял  количество чисел  может быть и несколько, просто они должны быть семизначными, то есть не нужно генерировать столько чисел, просто нужно с клавиатуры ввести несколько семизначных чисел, проверить их семизначность и сортировать по подходящему алгоритму

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да главное-то не в этом, а в функции `sort` :), которая применяет поразрядную сортировку. Два других ответа используют сортировку, основанную на сравнении, но для чисел можно и быстрее — O(n).

Comment: @Harry, мой ответ не использует сравнения и  работает за линейное время.

Comment: """Возиться с устойчивой сортировкой "на месте" не стал""" - я специально выяснял этот вопрос. Устойчивая сортировка "на месте" существует, я не сумел в ней разобраться - очень, очень сложный алгоритм.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Или простой, но очень неэффективный, сводящий O(n) на нет. Словом, я начал думать, мне казалось, что в принципе можно написать, но после вашего замечания — наверное, я был чересчур оптимистичен. Глубоко проблему не копал.

Answer (score 3):

Я с преподавателем соглашусь. Вы умеете сортировать только массивы в которых значения не повторяются. Есть ещё недостатки, но их можно обойти. А требование уникальности - это слишком строго. Например для входа `1000000 1000000 1000001` на выходе будет `1000000 1000001 1000001`. Не хорошо.

Можно сделать аналог быстрой сортировки, но вместо разделения по пивоту делить по значению бита. На первом проходе [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) переносит все числа с нулём в старшем бите в начало вектора. В конце вектора скапливаются числа с единичным старшим битом. Для обоих частей делаются рекурсивные вызовы со вторым по старшинству битом. И так далее. Можно убедится, что в итоге получится упорядоченный по возрастанию массив.

Хотя по структуре сортировка близка к быстрой, ведёт она себя по другому. Например: у быстрой сортировки сложность *NlogN* в среднем и *N<sup>2</sup>* в худшем. У сортировки ниже гарантированная линейная сложность.

Все ограничения на количество и значения чисел в векторах сняты:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using it = std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator;

void sort(it first, it last, uint32_t mask) {
    if (first != last && mask > 0) {
        it middle = std::partition(first, last, [mask](uint32_t v) {
            return (v & mask) == 0;
        });
        sort(first, middle, mask >> 1);
        sort(middle, last, mask >> 1);
    }
} 

void sort(it first, it last) {
    sort(first, last, ~((uint32_t)-1 >> 1));
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<uint32_t> a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        uint32_t v;
        std::cin >> v;
        a.push_back(v);
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            std::cout << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << a[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion sort.cpp 
>
> $ echo -e "6\n10 20 30 1 2 3" | ./a.out
> 1 2 3 10 20 30
> ```

Comment: Да, то что partition линейна (требует одного прохода по массиву) и ей не нужна дополнительная память довольно очевидно. Хороший вариант поразрядной сортировки на месте

Comment: Только quicksort с ее N log N для N < 4млрд получается все равно быстрее. У поразрядной сложность принято считать O(N * k), где k -- число разрядов. У нас тут это будет 32

Comment: @avp На случайном массиве из миллиарда чисел немного (типа, 113 против 117 секунд) обошла быструю `sort` из стандартной библиотеки...

Comment: "У сортировки ниже гарантированная линейная сложность" или NlogN?

Comment: @rotabor, сортировка "ниже" делает не более 32-х проходов по массиву. Сложность *32N*, то есть линейная.

Comment: А 32 это не logN?

Comment: @rotabor, для массива из 10^100 элементов 32 << log(10^100).

Comment: Ох, я перепутал N и количество разрядов N в двоичном представлении.

Comment: Так значит можно отсортировать массив натуральных чисел за линейное время?

Comment: @rotabor, натуральных чисел ограниченной разрядности - да.

Comment: Но у нас тут она всегда ограниченная

Comment: @rotabor, запрет сортировать быстрее чем NlogN действует только пока единственная разрешённая операция над элементами - сравнение `<`.

Comment: @rotabor, для чисел из стандартных типов - да. Для целых чисел из Питона - нет. Для строк или более сложных объектов - нет.

Comment: А чего для целых чисел из Питона нет? Разве проблема пройтись по битам всех слов? И строкам тоже можно сопоставить натуральные числа, в какой-то кодировке и с порядком сортировки по коду символа проще, а в какой-то сложнее.

Comment: @rotabor, *32* превратятся в *K*, где *K* разрядность самого большого числа. Это *K* может стать больше *logN*. Строкам нельзя сопоставить числа ограниченной разрядности. Различных строк больше чем чисел любой конечной разрядности.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148576/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and-rotabor).